How can I filter out OPTIONS method requests when recording a page script using JMeter's HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder or the bzm-Correlation Recorder?
There are many OPTIONS requests that I want to filter out directly during recording. Is there an effective method to do this?
I found that the headers of the OPTIONS requests do not contain the 'Content-type' key. I've tried filtering both in the include and exclude sections of the Content-type filter, but it was ineffective.
